# update < option > tag's 'selected' attribute according to url's city value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

This is my URL: www.xyz.com/index?city=NY
I am trying to update     < option >     tag's 'selected' attribute according to url's city value.
This is my partial html:

```
 <script>
    function loadCity(val)
    {
      window.location.assign("/do/index?city="+val); //script that reload's page as per selected city value.

    }
   $(document).ready ( function(){
        var cityValue= <?=$_GET['city'] ?>;        
        var k = getElementById(cityValue);         
        k.option.setAttribute('selected', true);   
    });​                                            //this function not working
 </script>




<select id="city" onchange="loadCity(this.value)">
                    <option>Cities</option>
                        <?php $cities=get_cities(); ?>   //get cities from an array
                        <?php foreach($cities as $city): ?>

                        <option id="<?= $city?>" value="<?= $city?>"><?= $city?></option>  

                        <?php endforeach; ?>  
                    </select>
```

Tried a bunch of other stuff, nothing seams to work.
Thanks in advance.(your response is greatly appreciated!)

Comment: try `$('select#city').val(1).change();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you setting the selected value in JavaScript? You could get rid of the entire document.ready part and do it in PHP.

```
<select id="city" onchange="loadCity(this.value)">
    <option>Cities</option>
    <?php $cities=get_cities(); ?>   //get cities from an array
    <?php foreach($cities as $city): ?>
         <option id="<?= $city; ?>" value="<?= $city; ?>" <?= $city == $_GET['city'] ? 'selected' : '' ?> ><?= $city; ?></option>  
    <?php endforeach; ?>  
</select>
```

Or in jQuery you could do

```
$("#city").val(cityValue);
```

Comment: The problem with using php to achieve this is, when you press back button on browser, it retains the latest 'selected' attr for < option > tag and loads previous page's content.

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to change

```
var cityValue= <?=$_GET['city'] ?>;
```

to

```
var cityValue= "<?=$_GET['city'] ?>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cityValue = "<?php echo $_GET['city']; ?>";
    $('#'+cityValue).prop('selected', true);
});​
```

Comment: how is a prop different from setAttribute ?

Comment: @Rao - One sets attributes, the other sets properties.

Comment: <select><option selected="true"> 1 </option></select> here, "selected" is attribute or a property?

Comment: Written in the HTML and set to a value of true, it's an attribute. That does'nt matter as what we're trying to change is the underlying property. As a sidenote it's either `selected="selected"` or just `selected`.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using javascript you could actually add condition on your for loop in your php file:

```
<select id="city" onchange="loadCity(this.value)">
   <option>Cities</option>
   <?php $cities=get_cities(); ?>   //get cities from an array
   <?php foreach($cities as $city): ?>

     <option id="<?= $city?>" value="<?= $city?>" <?php if(isset($_GET['city']) && $_GET['city'] == $city) echo "selected";?>><?= $city?></option>  

   <?php endforeach; ?>  
</select>
```

or by jQuery:

```
$('#city option[value="'+cityValue+'"]').prop("selected",true);
```